# How are IOUs for ground truth boxes in YOLO calculated?

Tags: computer-vision, yolo, bounding-box, jaccard-similarity

I know how IOU works during detection. However, while preparing targets from ground-truth for training, how is the IOU between a given object and all anchor boxes calculated?

**Is the ground truth bounding box aligned with an anchor box such that they share the same center? (width/2, height/2)**

I think this is the case but I want to hear from someone who has better knowledge of how training data is prepared for training in YOLO.

Comment: Can you perhaps provide a bit more context about the system you are talking about?

Comment: @OliverMason: Here's what I am talking about: https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/

In order to train, I need to prepare the training data. One of the fields is 'objectiveness factor' which is defined as IOU between the actual bounding box and best-fitting anchor box. My question is: how are these two boxes aligned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumption was correct: **the ground truth bounding box is aligned with an anchor box such that they share the same center**

In other words, only the widths and heights are used to calculate the ground truth IOU.